# Warning: mysqli_connect in PHP. Is this a serious note?

Tags: php

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target     machine actively refused it. in E:\xampp\htdocs\ss\docs\regional.php on line 15
The connection to the database could not be established.
```

Is this a serious error or can easily be ignored? The error message `'The connection to the database could not be established.'` is `expected to pop` but `not the warning text`. How do I remove it in that case. Below is the code I've used.

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'regional_data');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {die('The connection to the database could not be established.');}
```

EDIT: I have stopped SQL in the development area to test this and the message occurs at that time.

Comment: Mr. Alien which means in a live environment(uploaded to a real server) this would not appear except the desired message?

Comment: Try google, you'll get a solution for this..it is probably your `ports` are conflicting

Comment: @Mr.Alien - he is purposely breaking the mysql connection to test his error handling - as noted in his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your development environment it is completely legal to have the settions of display_errors on. This is the most easy way to see if things go wrong.

In productive environment you wouldn't set this to on, because the user usually does not need to know if PHP things go wrong - he even should not, because these messages might contain valuable information for attackers. That should only be communicated through dedicated error messages like inside your `die()`

So the warning in your output will go away if you disable display_errors, but you really want to have this warning in your logfile. Suppressing the warning with an `@` is not reccommended!

Comment: display_errors would only change whether or not the errors are added to the buffer and printed to the screen, they should still be logged depending on the `error_reporting` level, regardless.

Comment: Suppressing the `@` symbol is kind of a use case thing.... For example, its less resource intensive to suppress a divide by 0, than deal with it. There are also some functions that make it difficult to catch before a warning

Comment: I would argue that dealing with division by zero is less ressource intensive by using @. It's true for the developer. It is wrong for CPU ressources. The @ symbol is implicit changing of error_reporting to zero and back. And what is the correct result value of a "successful" division by zero? You have to deal with this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Probably only going to show the warning in your development environment due to how you have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` set.

[error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

[ini_set('display_errors', 0)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

**edit:** Just to clarify, if your error_reporting level includes warnings in your dev environment, they can be included in errors displayed to screen.  To test, set `displays_errors` to 0, as above right before that mysqli connect.

Answer (score -1):

You can suppress the warning by calling the function prepended with `@`, but better to be sure to fix the source of the error.

e.g. `$db = @mysqli_connect(...)`

Comment: Sure, yeah, why not. Just make the warning go away, and don't try to fix it. If a DB connection can't be made, that's really a fatal error to the rest of the code using it.

Comment: The OP was not asking for a solution to the problem, he was asking for a way to suppress the error. I clarified in my answer that he's better to fix the source of the error. He has error handling in place, already in his code.

Comment: The OP was likely implying that they want to _fix_ the error, not simply hide it.

Comment: I don't think so; he specifically wrote: "The error message is expected to pop but not the warning text. How do I remove it in that case. "

Comment: So if you had a disease that was killing you, would you take treatment to just hide the symptoms and pass away, or would you take treatment to cure the disease itself, to stop it from killing you? Would you recommend the former to someone else?

Comment: If I asked someone else to help me hide the symptoms, I would not expect them to deliver treatment.

Comment: The point is, you are promoting _very_ bad practices. Whether the OP asked to hide the warning or not, you shouldn't assume that's what they need. In this case, they need a fix for the _cause_ of the warning, so why not give them one?

Comment: Like I said above, he already has a fix in place: error catching is the next line after the connection. He was not looking for a fix, he was looking for a way to suppress the warning that PHP gives (so that his own error catching message can be displayed in `die()`). I don't think we'll see eye to eye on this, thanks for trying.

Comment: Just because its bad practice, doesnt mean this isnt a correct answer... Set Sail Media clearly mentioned this fact too, in the answer...